# What should be used in this sentence? You or her

Tags: grammar

"You're the only flower that gave me all her colours"

Is this sentence wrong? Some are saying that I should have used "your" in the place of "her". Though I think both are right.

This line is from a poem of mine-

For others-

you were just

one of the many beautiful

flowers.

For me-

you are the only flower

that made me colourful with

all her colours.

Comment: Is this being used as an analogy for something? I'm struggling to understand the meaning behind the sentence, and so answering might be a bit open ended. Is there a bit more context for this sentence?

Comment: @Smock that's from my poem

Comment: When I asked for context I was hoping for the surrounding few lines, to help get the gist of what is being said.

Comment: @Smock oh sorry. I've added that poem in the question

Comment: As it's poetry, and you *seem to be* using flower as a term for a female partner, it seems ok (and indeed preferable) to me to use '*her*' in this sense